# Finding whether the rows of a matrix in Matlab "fall" within the rows of another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `Ksets` in Matlab with size `Gx(l*N)` and a matrix `A` with size `MxN`.

Each row of `Ksets` can be decomposed into `l` sub-rows with size `1xN`.

Let me explain better with an example.

```
clear
N=3;
l=4;
G=2;
M=5;

Ksets=[1 2 3      5 6 7      9 10 11   0 0 0;
       13 14 15   1 2 3      21 22 23  1 1 1]; %Gx(l*N)

A=[1 2 3; 
   5 6 7; 
   21 22 23; 
   1 2 3;
   0 0 0]; %MxN
```

In the example:

- row `1` of `Ksets` is composed of `l` sub-rows with size `1xN`:  `[1 2 3]`, `[5 6 7]`, `[9 10 11]`, `[0 0 0]`;
- row `2` of `Ksets` is composed of `l` sub-rows with size `1xN`:  `[13 14 15]`, `[1 2 3]`, `[21 22 23]`, `[1 1 1]`.

I assume that each row of `Ksets` does not contain equal sub-rows.

I would like your help to construct a matrix `Response` with size `GxM` with `Response(g,m)=1` if the row `A(m,:)` is equal to one of the `l` sub-rows of  `Ksets(g,:)` and zero otherwise.

Continuing the example above

```
Response= [1 1 0 1 1; 
           1 0 1 1 0]; %GxM
```

This code does what I want:

```
Responsecorrectmy=zeros(G, M);
for x=1:G
    for c=1:l
        Responsecorrectmy(x,:)=Responsecorrectmy(x,:)+...
                               ismember(A,Ksets(x,(c-1)*N+1:c*N), 'rows').';
    end
end
```

My code consists of 2 loops which is undesirable because in my real algorithm `G,l` are big. Do you have suggestions without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a little reshaping and dimension-permuting:

```
Response = permute(any(all(bsxfun(@eq, reshape(Ksets.', N, [], G), permute(A, [2 3 4 1])), 1), 2), [3 4 1 2]);
```

This works as follows:

1. `reshape(Ksets.', N, [], G)` reshapes `Ksets` into an `N`×`l`×`G` 3D-array so that each subrow is now separated from the others.
2. `bsxfun(@eq, ..., permute(A, [2 3 4 1]))` creates an `N`×`l`×`G`×`M` 4D-array with the result of comparing each element of the 3D-array from step 1 with each value in `A`.
3. `all(..., 1)` tests if *all* the elements of each subrow (i.e. first dimension) match. `any(...,2)` tests if this happens for *any* subrow of one of the original rows (i.e.  second dimension).
4. `permute(..., [3 4 1 2])` removes the first two dimensions (which became singleton in step 3), giving the desired `G`×`M` result. (It would not be safe to use `squeeze` for this because it would incorrectly remove the third dimension if `G=1`).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to do this vectorized, especially if the subsets you're trying to compare to are embedded in each row.  What can be done for efficiency is to change the `Ksets` into a 3D matrix where each slice contains those subsets formatted into a 2D matrix where each subset is on a per-row basis.  You can then use `ismember` combined with using just one loop on each row individually and populate your results.

```
Ksets2 = permute(reshape(Ksets.', [N l G]), [2 1 3]);
Response = false(G, M);
for i = 1 : G
    Response(i, :) = ismember(A, Ksets2(:,:,i), 'rows')';
end
```

The first statement reshapes your data so that it becomes a 3D matrix, but because of MATLAB's column major processing, and because your subsets are in row major, we have to transpose the data prior to reshaping.  However, this results in each column being in a subset, so we have to transpose each slice independently with the `permute` operation.

Once that's done, we allocate a matrix of the desired size, then loop through each row in `Ksets` (now transformed into rows of subsets) to produce the desired result.

We get:

```
>> Response

Response =

  2×5 logical array

   1   1   0   1   1
   1   0   1   1   0
```

Comment: @LuisMendo ohhhhh but they're all real integer values so it's ok! :D

Comment: @LuisMendo fine. Changed it :P.

Comment: You know my pet peeves... :-)