# Find equal rows between two Matlab matrices

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, rows, set-intersection

I have a matrix `index` in Matlab with size `GxN` and a matrix `A` with size `MxN`.

Let me provide an example before presenting my question.

```
clear
N=3;
G=2;
M=5;

index=[1  2  3;
       13 14 15]; %GxN

A=[1  2  3; 
   5  6  7; 
   21 22 23; 
   1  2  3;
   13 14 15]; %MxN
```

I would like your help to construct a matrix `Response` with size `GxM` with `Response(g,m)=1` if the row `A(m,:)` is equal to `index(g,:)` and zero otherwise.

Continuing the example above

```
Response= [1 0 0 1 0; 
           0 0 0 0 1]; %GxM
```

This code does what I want (taken from a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118832/finding-whether-the-rows-of-a-matrix-in-matlab-fall-within-the-rows-of-another) - just to clarify: the current question is different)

```
Response=permute(any(all(bsxfun(@eq, reshape(index.', N, [], G), permute(A, [2 3 4 1])), 1), 2), [3 4 1 2]);
```

However, the command is extremely slow for my real matrix sizes (`N=19, M=500, G=524288`). I understand that I will not be able to get huge speed but anything that can improve on this is welcome.

Comment: I highly doubt this is much more improveable. You may be able to do it by instead of using 1-liners, break the code into pieces and time it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Aproach 1: computing distances

If you have the Statistics Toolbox:

```
Response = ~(pdist2(index, A));
```

or:

```
Response = ~(pdist2(index, A, 'hamming'));
```

This works because [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) computes the distance between each pair of rows. Equal rows have distance `0`. The logical negation `~` gives `1` for those pairs of rows, and `0` otherwise.

## Approach 2: reducing rows to unique integer labels

This approach is faster on my machine:

```
[~,~,u] = unique([index; A], 'rows');
Response = bsxfun(@eq, u(1:G), u(G+1:end).');
```

It works by reducing rows to unique integer labels (using the third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)), and comparing the latter instead of the former.

For your size values this takes approximately 1 second on my computer:

```
clear
N = 19; M = 500; G = 524288;
index = randi(5,G,N); A = randi(5,M,N);
tic
[~,~,u] = unique([index; A], 'rows');
Response = bsxfun(@eq, u(1:G), u(G+1:end).');
toc
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 1.081043 seconds.
```

Comment: `findgroups` might be quicker than using the 3rd output of `unique`. Not done speed tests in the past but believe it does the same thing.

Comment: @Wolfie I think `findgroups` requires grouping variables to be vectors. So the matrices here would have to be split into their columns, which takes time. Also, `findgroups` internally uses the third output of `unique`, so I doubt it's faster

Comment: Ah ignore me then, didn't realise the two were intertwined! The 2nd option is quite a bit quicker than my reshaping method which surprised me.

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, for the OP's sizes your method takes 5 times more than my second approach on my computer. I guess when sizes are large it's beneficial to reduce a dimension as soon as possible (my second approach) even if that takes time

Answer (score 7):

MATLAB has a multitude of functions for [working with sets](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/set-operations.html), including `setdiff`, `intersect`, `union` etc. In this case, you can use the [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
[~, Loc] = ismember(A,index,'rows');
```

Which gives:

```
Loc =
     1
     0
     0
     1
     2
```

And `Response` would be constructed as follows:

```
Response = (1:size(index,1) == Loc).';
```

```
Response =
  2×5 logical array
   1   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how to get `Response` from there.

Answer (score 3):

You could `reshape` the matrices so that each row instead lies along the 3rd dimension. Then we can use implicit expansion (see `bsxfun` for R2016b or earlier) for equality of all elements, and `all` to aggregate on the rows (i.e. false if not all equal for a given row).

```
Response = all( reshape( index, [], 1, size(index,2) ) == reshape( A, 1, [], size(A,2) ), 3 );
```

You might even be able to avoid some reshaping by using `all` in another dimension, but it's easier for me to visualise it this way.